# Is it possible to run persistent tcp listening socket on iOS, even when my App is not the foreground app?

Tags: ios

The iOS APIs allow me to open listening sockets for example using the `ServerSocket` class, however if my App is not in the foreground I assume I won't receive any requests sent to the socket. Is there a way I can keep the listening socket open in the background? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having researched this further I am now convinced that listening sockets on iOS in most circumstances are only useful if your app is the foreground.

The only methods I have found that allow a persistent listening socket in the background abuse other parts of the API e.g. location API so are not suitable for anything beyond an academic demonstration of the capability.